# Set a tuple as column name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I'm trying to set a pandas column name to a tuple.
Little notice: The column name is already a tuple that I'm trying to replace with another tuple.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXmUG.png)
I tried this`tab.rename(columns = {valeur[0] : cle}, inplace = True )`
'cle' is my new tuple (6, 9), and 'valeur[0]' is the column name (7.25, 7.35).

I'm getting the error : 'Names should be list-like for a MultiIndex'

Comment: Note this issue is only observed when the dataframe contains data. An empty dataframe works fine with the provided code.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please avoid using images of text.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]], columns=[(7.25, 7.35), (7.35, 7.5)])
new_cols = df.columns.values.copy()
new_cols[0] = (6, 9)
df.columns = new_cols
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   (6, 9)  (7.35, 7.5)
0       0            0
1       0            0
2       1            1
```

Comment: Also, perhaps someone with a deeper knowledge of Pandas may comment on whether modifying and index directly through `.values` is actually valid. I have not found any reference to the opposite, so I'm assuming it is.

Comment: You shouldn't modify values directly. I've found it to cause issues in crazy ways  which you could never imagine possible unless you wrote the Pandas source. A copy's fine +1.

Comment: @jpp Thanks for the info, I've changed it to use a copy instead then.

Comment: Or perhaps `df.columns = [(6, 9)]+df.columns[1:].tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: [Option to suppress automatic conversion of tuples to MultiIndex](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11799).

A comment from a principal developer:

> You can do this, but using tuples as index is VERY awkward and barely
>   supported. These are much more naturally represented (and performant)
>   as MultiIndexes. I have never seen a case where this is actually a
>   good idea.

The proposed solution in that thread suggests using `tupleize_cols=False`:

```
tab = pd.DataFrame([[1], [2], [3]], columns=[(7.25, 7.35)])

valeur = [(7.25, 7.35)]
cle = (6, 9)

tab.columns = pd.Index([i if i != valeur[0] else cle for i in tab],
                       tupleize_cols=False)

print(tab)

   (6, 9)
0       1
1       2
2       3
```